# change input autofill styling

Tags: css, input, autocomplete, autofill

I have inputs that have white background and dark text but when I type and the browser autocompletes, the styling changes. I know the browsers do this and I've found a fix for it on Chrome but not for Safari and Firefox. On safari, the text still turns white (Strangely is turns to the color I wrote when I save the text editor a second time). Firfox still makes the background yellow. Here is my current code for the inputs.

```
input:-webkit-autofill::first-line,
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
input:-webkit-autofill:active,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #fff inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #fff inset !important;
  // background-color: red !important;
  // background-clip: content-box !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #002169 !important;
  font-family: 'Europa';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style autofilled inputs using `:-webkit-autofill`

Even in firefox with the webkit-prefix!

To change the background color, there is the box-shadow trick.
And for Firefox you need additionally `filter:none`.

```css
:-webkit-autofill { 
    filter:none; /* needed for firefox! */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 100px rgba(38, 163, 48, 0.212) inset;
}
```

How and if this works with Safari I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover,
input:-webkit-autofill:focus,
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px red !important;
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

The above code will make the background of the inputs red and the text white.